# Modify .update function for dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, hook

I would like to know how can I modify the already existing .update function from dict.

For example:

```
import __builtin__

def test(a):
    print a

__builtin__.update = test
```

So when I'll use X.update again it will show a print saying the values.

What I mean:

```
test = {}
test.update({ "Key" : "Value" })
```

I want a print showing the following texts: "Key" and "Value"

Kind Regards,
Denis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class dict2(dict):
    def update(*args,**kwargs):
        print "Update:",args,kwargs
        dict.update(*args,**kwargs)

d = dict2(a=5,b=6,c=7)
d.update({'x':10})
```

as im sure you noticed you cannot simply do `dict.update=some_other_fn` ... however there are ways of doing it if you are both determined and foolhardy enough ....

```
~> sudo pip install forbiddenfruit
~> python
...
>>> from forbiddenfruit import curse
>>> def new_update(*args,**kwargs): 
       print "doing something different..."
>>> curse(dict,"update",new_update)
```

Comment: Is there a way I can do it without a class?

Comment: dict is a class already so you are already using a class ... but no you may not just say `dict.update = some_other_func` as Im sure you are aware (since you probably tried it in your sample code...) (well thats not entirely true ... updating answer)

Answer (score 0):

you could override the update method by subclassing `dict`.

```
from collections import Mapping 

class MyDict(dict):
    def update(self, other=None, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(other, Mapping):
            for k, v in other.items():
                print(k, v)
            super().update(other, **kwargs)

m = MyDict({1:2})
m.update({2:3})
```

Comment: I don't really want to use a class.Is there a way I can do it without it?